# Issue coming while connecting google datafusion pipeline to mysql database

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am connecting MYSQL database to google bigquery through datafusion pipeline,i used a jdbc driver jar file, i installed it and put details into source pipeline, at the time of browsing data at connection database(mysql) i put detail of host name,port name, user id and password properly now i am getting this error - "**Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.**"
Help me with this....

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should add the code that causes the problem to your question.

Comment: Can you please explain with more details the steps you took?

Answer (score 0):

Is it private instance of the Cloud Data Fusion or public? For public CDF instances, mysql database should be on public IP address and allow connections. For private CDF instances, make sure you have followed the instructions here https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip, mainly the vpc peering is setup.